# Generating nCr combinations of given set in java

Tags: java, combinations, ncr

I want java implementation of generating nCr combinations of given set.
e.g if set is {"java","php",".net","python"}
program should return all possible nCr sets of given set.

Comment: is this homework; if yes please re-tag it. First of all you should let us know what you did about this?

Answer (score 4):

Adapting [Gosper's hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Applications), this works up to n = 64.

```
List<String> inputs;
List<List<String>> ncr = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (long x = (1 << r) - 1; (x >>> r) == 0;) {
  // x contains a 1 bit for each input we should choose;
  // iterate over the 1 bits of x
  long y = x;
  List<String> combination = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(y);
       y != 0; i = Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(y)) {
    combination.add(inputs.get(i));
    y &= ~(1 << i);
  }
  long u = x & -x;
  long v = u + x;
  x = v + ((v ^ x) / u) >>> 2;
}
```